# Internationalize an XML file using a PropertyPlaceHolder?

Tags: xml, properties, internationalization

I know it's possible to use keys (referenced in a property file) inside an XML file thanks to a PropertyPlaceHolder. I would like to know if it's possible to do a similar thing with internationalization. Is there a language resolution in the xml or something ?

Don't know if it can change anything but I'm using Spring & Struts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible. And it's probably not necessary anyway. As a matter of fact, what I want to internationalize is something like :

```
<bean id="mapPriorities" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
        <property name="example">
            <map>
                <entry key="3" value="Normal" />
                <entry key="5" value="Urgent" />
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I would like for instance to have "Normal" and "Urgent" translated in different languages. But it's silly because when the bean is created, there is no way to resolve the browser language.

Thus, in this case, the question is not a matter of XML Internationalization really...

If anyone comes to have a brainbug like me on this subject, here is the simple solution : just put a "key" in the key option of the entry, like key="key.priority.normal". Then use a ResourceBundle to get the internationalized value on display in your java code.

Sorry for my quite bad question.